# Django , want to load a website and then update it

Tags: javascript, python, ajax, django

I'm new to Django and Python so bear with me.
I'm trying to submit a form (in `test.html` page) And once the form is submitted I want to load a new page(`test.html/web1.html`) and then the page will display continuous updates on tasks running.

This currently works on a single page, where I submit the form I get the updates on the same page using AJAX. I want to implement this on a new page. Below is my code.

*test.js*

```
$('#Submit_button').on('submit',function(event){
    event.preventDefault();
    console.log("form submitted!")  
    call_func();  
}); 

function  call_func() { 
    $.ajax({
       url : "start_task/", // the endpoint
       data:{...,'init':call_func.i}, // call_func.i to iterate 2 times
    headers: {Accept: "application/json"},
    success : function(json) {  
        if(call_func.i==0){
            call_func.i=1;
            call_func();                
        }               
        else ...
```

*views.py*

```
def start_task(request):
    if request.method == 'POST':
        init = request.POST.get('init')
        print('init =',init)
        if init==0:
            return render(request, 'my_app/web1.html')    
        elif init==1:
            # work on updates
            return HttpResponse(
                json.dumps(response_data),
                content_type="application/json"
            )
```

*html*

```
<form action="/test.html/start_task/" method="POST" id="Submit_button">
```

How do I use AJAX only for the latter part (to update the new page) and just load the page first after submit?

Comment: Add a get endpoint on your start_task where you return the JSON data that you need to update the task page.

Answer (score 0):

I think you need something like [HttpResponseRedirect](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/request-response/#django.http.HttpResponseRedirect) instead of HttpResponse:

```
       if form.is_valid(): # validation
           # Process your data
           # ...
           return HttpResponseRedirect('/new_page_url/')
```

Comment: I tried    
         
          HttpResponseRedirect ('web1.html',json.dumps(response_data),
                content_type="application/json")
but it appends the new page to the old page path . i.e the old page and the new page are under the same folder template/my_app/....html , but it gives
Not Found: /test.html/start_task/web1.html